# Audio output 2 devices

Tags: html, audio, raspberry-pi, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm currently developing a web app which has to emit music on speakers while the user listens microphones input on headphones.
So what I need is to tell my browser to output one audio stream on a certain device and the other stream on another device.
Do anyone knows if there's a way to do that ? I read a lot about the WebAudioApi, but it doesn't seem to provide any solution, as the 'context.destination' is unique and defined by the system.

Another solution I consider is to use a raspberry pi with an audio card so I could send the audio stream through a websocket and play it on my device connected to the raspberry. It's just a thought, the thing is that I have absolutely 0 experience with that. Is this possible to do that or should I forget it ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The API currently does not support simultaneous output to multiple independent audio devices.  It's most likely the way this will be supported is by creating multiple AudioContexts on different devices; but this isn't specified or implemented by anyone today.

You *should* be able to access multiple outputs of a more-than-two-channel audio device, though - so you can do this, it will just have to be on a single device (not one device for speakers, and one for headphones).